# How to configure Android Studio 4.1.1 to work with an outdated Gradle project?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, gradle

I am using Android Studio 4.1.1 to complete a Beginner's Android course that was last updated in 2015/2016. I don't know how to use Gradle and GitHub as I am new to this.

This is the link to the GitHub repository of the project:
https://github.com/udacity/ud839_Miwok/tree/Starter-code

I downloaded and extracted the zip file and imported the project, and have even tried importing it directly from the Version Control option. However, whenever I try to sync the project, the following error appears and the Gradle sync fails.

Incremental Java compilation is an incubating feature.

It asked me to install hundreds of files and plugins which I did but nothing works. Please help.
I know this is badly written, but there are so many different errors everytime I try to run it, I am overwhelmed.

Comment: might not be an option or a popular opinion, but i don't think there's any value in learning from tutorials which are 4-5 years old. instead of wasting time trying to make ancient code work (things which you most probably won't even be able to use anymore) i'd suggest just getting a new tutorial

Comment: It is Google's official course on Udacity.

Comment: Could you please suggest some?

Comment: i honestly can't, we all learn in different ways and have our preferences, but i'm sure there are a ton of resources available to you on youtube or online

Comment: Here you can download old versions of Android Studio and they should work with old versions of gradle plugin: https://developer.android.com/studio/archive